# When i run the code of curve matching,error comes

Tags: c++, c, opencv, visual-studio-debugging

I run the code on this page,[enter link description here](https://github.com/royshil/CurveMatching)

some error comes.

1. First,"#include " and "#include "/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/Eigen"
   " is necesary in the file std.h?I can not find these included file.
2. Second,when i comment out the code lines "#include " and "#include "/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/Eigen",then i run the code,many error comes,as follow[image]

I tried,but failed,can someone help me?Thanks in advands!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org) is a C++ library for linear algebra that you need to install and include the correct headers.
The source code seems to target Linux. `/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/Eigen` implies a unix path.
You are on Windows, that won't work. you have to modify the code to work.

Comment: Agreed. Even though you can probably generate a Visual Studio project for CurveMatching using CMake this include will have to be adjusted at minimum since it uses a POSIX path which will not work with Visual Studio.